# Populate a table based on the value entered in a tetbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I have a SQL Server database with a table called Employee that has a few columns.

Using Razor Pages, I have already created my Model along with the DBContext class.

I used the basic CRUD template in my Web app.

What I'm trying to accomplish now is I have an input textbox as well as a input button with the value of Search.

When the user enters say number 1 and clicks Search, I want a table to populate with the record information based on that value entered

i.e. SELECT Name, Department
FROM Employee
WHERE DepartmentID = 1;

I'm receiving this error when I click on the Submit button

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Here is my model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Employee
    {
        [Key] public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Department { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime DateofJoining { get; set; }
        public string PhotoFileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my DB Context

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class CompanyContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = null!;

        public CompanyContext() {}
        public CompanyContext(DbContextOptions<CompanyContext> options) : base(options) {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("EmployeeID");
                entity.Property(e => e.DateofJoining).HasColumnType("date");
                entity.Property(e => e.Department).HasMaxLength(500);
                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeName).HasMaxLength(500);
                entity.Property(e => e.PhotoFileName).HasMaxLength(500);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Partial View _DisplaySearchPartial.cshtml ,this is the partial view I'm trying to display when the button is clicked

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>
<p>Search Result</p>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table>
        <tr><td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)</td></tr>

        @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
         {
            <tr><td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => item.EmployeeName)</td></tr>
         }
    </table>
 }
 else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@page
@model PracticeApp.Pages.IndexModel
@{ViewData["Title"] = "Index";}

<form method="post">
    @Html.TextBox("Entervalue")
    <button type="submit" id="search">Search Value</button>

    <div id="result">
        <partial name="_DisplaySearchPartial" model="Model.Employee" />
    </div>
</form>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#search").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                       url: "/Index?handler=Search",
                       type: "POST",
                       data: { value: $("#Entervalue").val() },
                       headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input: hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                       success: function(data) { $("#result").html(data); }
                  });
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is the code-begind for my Index

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PracticeApp.Models;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CompanyContext _context;

        public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; } = default!;

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (_context.Employees != null)
            {
                Employee = await _context.Employees.ToListAsync();
            }
        }

        public ActionResult OnPostSearch(int value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplaySearchPartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == value).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem. You tell us what you want to achieve and you post a bunch of code. What's the problem? What EXACTLY does that code not do that you want or do that you don't want? Is there a compilation error or run-time exception? If so, where and what's the error message? Getting the input from the view into the controller, retrieving the data, and getting the output from the controller back to the view are all separate and distinct operations. Which one are you having a problem with? You need to be specific.

Comment: Hi @TheGame1083, could you pls share your model design?

Comment: Hi @Rena I have provided the Model for you as well as additional code I missed

Comment: I fixed it Rena, it worked like a charm ty, now I have to see how to implement a 2nd partial view with that main view based on that entered value since both view share the same value

Comment: Ty @Rena already marked as answered. I created a new thread for a similar issue using INNER JOINS [link]here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74283217/populate-a-table-with-2-columns-for-2-different-models-based-on-the-value-entere?noredirect=1#comment131145666_74283217

Comment: Hi @TheGame1083, for your new thread, it seems you do not know how to write the linq to bind the two models, right?

Comment: @Rena yes, if the user enters 1, the first model populates, from that list, if the user clicks on a name, the next model appears as a new column or new table based on that same value that was initially entered.

Comment: I was initially trying to do the results in a select drop down list but I couldn't figure it out, it would be easier for the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'PracticeApp.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[PracticeApp.Models.Employee]'

You use `<partial name="Search" />` in your main page(`Index.cshtml`) without specifying the model, so it will pass the main page model(`IndexModel`) by default. But your partial view requires type of `IEnumerable<Models.Employee>`, which does not match the passed model.

Besides, the handler in Razor Page should be `OnGetHandlerName` or `OnPostHandlerName`. Also, `@Url.Action()` and `@Html.BeginForm` are all used for MVC controller action instead of Razor Page.

Here is a whole working demo about how to change the result by search bar:

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h1>Index</h1>
<form method="post">
    @Html.TextBox("Entervalue")
    <button type="button" id="search">search</button>

    <div id="result">
        <partial name="Search" model="Model.Employee" />
    </div>
</form>

@section scripts
{
<script>
    $("#search").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "/Index?handler=Sub",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#Entervalue").val() },
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                success: function(data) { $("#result").html(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly CompanyContext _context;
    public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; } = default!;
    public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (_context.Employees != null)
        {
            Employee = await _context.Employees.ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public ActionResult OnPostSub(int value)
    {
        return Partial("Search", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == value).ToList());
    }
}
```

Partial View named `Search.cshtml` which located in `Pages/Shared` folder:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>

<p>Search Result</p>
@if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => item.EmployeeName)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}
```

Result:

[image]