# Populate a table with 2 columns for 2 different Models based on the value entered in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, razor-pages

I have a SQL Server database with a 2 tables called Employee and Department that have a few columns, both tables share a common column DepartmentID.

Using Razor Pages, I have already created my Models along with the DBContext class.

I have an input textbox as well as a input button with the value of Search.

When the user enters say number 1 and clicks Search, I want a table to populate with the record information based on that value entered from both tables. Basically a JOIN of 2 tables since they share the same Column Name

Basically this:

SELECT Departments.DepartmentName, Employees.EmployeeName, Employees.DateofJoining
FROM Employees
INNER JOIN Departments ON Departments.DepartmentID=Employees.DepartmentID
WHERE Departments.DepartmentID = 1;

Would I need to create a 3rd model or can I call both Models in the same Partial View?

CompanyContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class CompanyContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = null!;

        public CompanyContext() {}
        public CompanyContext(DbContextOptions<CompanyContext> options) : base(options) {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentId).HasColumnName("DepartmentID");

                entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentName).HasMaxLength(500);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeId).HasColumnName("EmployeeID");

                entity.Property(e => e.DateofJoining).HasColumnType("date");

                entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentId).HasColumnName("DepartmentID");

                entity.Property(e => e.DepartmentName).HasMaxLength(500);

                entity.Property(e => e.EmployeeName).HasMaxLength(500);

                entity.Property(e => e.PhotoFileName).HasMaxLength(500);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Department.cs

```
namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Employee.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace PracticeApp.Models
{
    public partial class Employee
    {
        [Key] public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime? DateofJoining { get; set; }
        public string? PhotoFileName { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

_DisplaySearchPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Employee>
<p>Search Result</p>

@if (Model.Count() != 0)
 {
    <table>
        <tr><td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EmployeeName)</td></tr>

        @foreach (Models.Employee item in Model)
         {
            <tr><td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => item.EmployeeName)</td></tr>
         }
    </table>
 }
 else
{
    <p>No data</p>
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{ ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; }

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("Entervalue")</td>
            <td><button type="button" id="search">Search</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="result">

    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#search").click(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Index?handler=Display",
                type: "POST",
                data: { value: $("#Entervalue").val() },
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                success: function(data) { $("#result").html(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Code-behind Index

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CompanyContext _context;

        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        public ActionResult OnPostDisplay(int value)
        {
            return Partial("_DisplaySearchPartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == value).ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to populate the first column with the Employee model, Im trying to populate the 2nd Model on the next column of the same table

Comment: A "View Model" is often a combination of entities and even anything else a View will need for display. Personally, I never use an Entity Model directly because they almost never meet the needs of the view and they can introduce over-posting vulnerabilities if you are not careful.

Comment: do you mean you want to populate the properties of department and sort the Employees with their department?